# how to add class as a parameter to form_multiselect in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to add this class `class="form-control"`

to multiselect input function in codeigniter and i don't know how to do this

```
<?= form_multiselect('roles[]', $roles, set_value('roles[]',$group_roles)) ?>
```

i read the documentation and i dont understand how to do this,can anyone explain ho to add classes to this input

Parameters:

> $name

(string) – Field name

> $options

(array) – An associative array of options to be listed

> $selected

(array) – List of fields to mark with the selected attribute

> $extra

(mixed) – Extra attributes to be added to the tag either as an array or a literal string

Comment: add your code please

Comment: form_multiselect is not changed in the two versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer simple like this

```
                    <?= form_multiselect('roles[]',$roles,$group_roles,'class="form-control"') ?>
```